# Angular: routing inside an ng-zorro modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-routing, ng-zorro-antd

I have an Angular project where I created some components ready for reuse, and they will be created with an NG-ZORRO modal using `NzModalService.create()`. For example,

```js
// welcome.component.ts
export class WelcomeComponent {
  constructor(private modal: NzModalService) {}

  foo() {
    this.modal.create({
      nzTitle: 'This is a modal',
      nzContent: SharedComponent
    });
  }
}
```

where `WelcomeComponent` is one of my major pages and `SharedComponent` is used as content of the modal created. **Each component has its own module as well as a routing module.**

Now I want to make some steps guide in a modal like above, and use routing to navigate between steps. And for that, I wrote my code like this:

**step-guide.component.html**

```html
<ul nz-menu nzMode="horizontal">
  <li nz-menu-item>
    <a [routerlink]="'step1'">Step 1</a>
  </li>
  <li nz-menu-item>
    <a [routerlink]="[{outlets: {stepGuide: ['step2']}}]">Step 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div>
  <router-outlet name='stepGuide'></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**step-guide-routing.module.ts**

```js
// imports omitted...

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'step1', loadChildren: () => import('../step1/step1.module').then(m => m.Step1Module) },
  { path: 'step2', outlet: 'stepGuide', loadChildren: () => import('../step2/step2.module').then(m => m.Step2Module) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StepGuideRoutingModule {}
```

I tried different ways to make it work, but never succeeded. For the code combination above, when I click Step 1 the modal just disappears and the main window is guided to an empty page. When I click Step 2 nothing happens and the console outputs no error at all. Removing the name from `<router-outlet>` yields the same result.

I also tried to wrap my route paths with a parent (such as `{path: 'welcome', children: ...}`) because the modal can be created by clicking a button in a component whose path in `app-routing.module` is `/welcome`. And this would cause error like `welcome/step1` not matching any route.

The actual problem is, **the modal is not hard-coded in HTML and can be created in different components, so I can't bind it to a specific path (which doesn't work, either.)** But I hope my routing can work inside the modal wherever it is created. What should I do?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Well I ended up using `Tab` instead of modal although it is not 100% what I expected, because it is less complicated.